# How to update size of group in fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

In the fabricjs library, the class fabric.Group offers a **.addWithUpdate(...)** method which *Adds an object to a group; Then recalculates group's dimension, position.*

Is there a way to force the update?

I am creating a group using fabric.util.groupSVGElements( array_of_fabric_elements ), which does not update its size.

I have tried fabric.Group.setObjectsCoords(), but it throws a "not a function" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which `fabric.js` version do you use?
`fabric.util.groupSVGElements` didn't create `fabric.Group` – it created `fabric.PathGroup`.

If you want to create a `fabric.Group` please use:

```
var group = new fabric.Group([obj1, obj2, ...]);
canvas.add(group);
```

If you want to add/remove object from your group you can do this with:

```
group.addWidthUpdate(object)/group.removeWidthUpdate(object)
```

Both functions recalculate the group dimensions.

Comment: wow ... I had no idea: _it created fabric.PathGroup_ ... I thought it DID create a Group ... I never even thought to check.

Comment: I suppose that this a solution because it really shows that I was in error in the first place, and it points me in the right direction.

Comment: There is a typo in the answer. Correct function names are: group.addWithUpdate(object) and group.removeWithUpdate(object).